# How to read a space character from a text file in c++

Tags: c++

In c++, ascii characters has a default value. Like ! has a value of 33, "," has also a value of 44 and so on.

inside my text file "hehe.txt" is. `;!,.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("hehe.txt");
    if(file.eof()) 
        return 0;
    char ascii;

    while(file>>ascii) {
        std::cout << (int)ascii << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Output is `59 33 44 46`.

Edit: How may I prevent space to be ignored as being read from the text file when I run my program? Suppose I added space after the last character `;!,.`thus, the output must be `59 33 44 46 32`. Hope someone could give me an idea how to do it.

Comment: I presume you've tried it? What happens?

Comment: What is the question actually? What happens if you add the space to your file, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Just me don't get what hes asking?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall the space is just being ignored when i run my program,

Comment: @SvendHansen i took search on net of some which could be serve as my guide how to make or how to give value to a space and do it but i got nothing even here.

Comment: Do you mean, your `file>>ascii` skips spaces in `hehe.txt`, ignores them, even if you add them there?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "Lets say the space has a value of 32."...? ASCII code for space *is* 32, you have no say in that.

Comment: @hyde exactly... even how many spaces i put, still ignores

Comment: @hyde as I know space "on my own" its not part of the ASCII thats why I said this line  "Lets say the space has a value of 32.". Since you said that I would be thankful for that, for this is my first time to know/interact the default values of ASCII including the space and as an additional knowledge to me .

Comment: If your platform uses ASCII encoding, the characters will always have [these](http://www.asciitable.com/) integer values. They aren't defaults, because that implies they can change. They're fixed by the standard.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the separator. When you use `file >> ascii` this will "eat" all your spaces as these are used as separators.

You can use `getline` and then iterate over all chars in the string.

```
std::ifstream file("../../temp.txt");
if(!file)return 0;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line, '\0')){
    for(char ascii : line){
        std::cout<<(int)ascii << " ";
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

What is also possible, as dornhege says, is:

```
  while(file >> std::noskipws >> ascii){
    std::cout << (int) ascii << "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the separator to another character?

Comment: No. It's fixed for all `stream::operator >>`. It is quite annoying.

Comment: @RedX  i got an error on line for(char ascii : line), it says "expected primary-expression before char" but i got exact output of dornhege advice.

Comment: @kersey that is because that syntax is C++11. If your compiler does not support that you have to use: `for(string::iterator it = line.begin(), end  = line.end(); it != end; ++it)`

Answer (score 4):

The istream object will skip whitespace as the "  " (32) by default. Try adding `>> std::noskipws` to your stream before reading.

Comment: +1 for nice additional info ("Try adding ...").